# How to read from secondary mongodb with a connection string

Tags: database, mongodb, readonly

I am trying to run a query through mongos instance on the secondary servers. I connected in this way: `mongo mongodb://IP:27019/?readPreference=secondaryPreferred`

when I run a query and add `.explain()`. I see that he ran it through the primary.

Please note that all seconderies are up. I use mongodb version 3.4
and the environment is sharded

Comment: That looks fine [according to the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.readPreference). Does dropping the 'preferred' make a difference, i.e. just 'secondary'? It may be that mongo is just ignoring your preference. Can you replicate this by setting the option in the client rather than using the URL?

Comment: I also tried the 'secondary' option and the result was similar.
I understand that 'secondaryPreferred' more strongly because it always transfers to secondary if they are available.

I have to use the URL in this case.

Comment: Sure - I meant try setting the property manually for testing to try and understand MongoDB’s behaviour here. But unless there’s a debug / verbose mode on the client so you can see trace of why it’s deciding to use primary not secondary I’ve run out of ideas now - sorry.